# stepping through variable length lines of integers

Tags: c, input, scanf

I am trying to read in a file that goes a little something like this...

```
52 12 123 1
4 2 11 
9 88 1 23 42
```

And the file goes on with each line changing
I know how to read in each number individually using a loop with fscanf, but I want to read the first number to be the parent in a tree and the rest of the line be its children.  So this would make 3 trees with 52, 4, and 9 being parents.  How should I go about reading the rest of the line and add each int to the proper tree? I am coding this in c.

Comment: Read the lines with `fgets` and then convert the numbers with `strtol`.  Note that the second argument to `strtol` will be a pointer that you can pass to the next call to `strtol`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading by line and then parsing the line-input into integers may provide a bit more flexibility. Using pointers to step through the lines until the null terminator is found accommodates the differing number of integers per line. The following is a quick hack at a solution that does a good job on the sample input provided. The code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc < 2 ) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: insufficient input, usage: %s char *fname\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file;
    char *lineptr = NULL;
    char *sptr = NULL, *eptr = NULL;
    size_t n = 0;
    ssize_t len = 0;
    int cnt = 0;
    int parent = 1;

    if ((file = fopen (argv[1], "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf (stderr, "Error: file open failed for '%s'\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    while ((len = getline (&lineptr, &n, file)) != -1 ) {
        /* strip newline */
        if (*(lineptr+len-1) == '\n') {
            *(lineptr+len-1) = '\0';
            len -= 1;
        }

        /* test output of line to parse */
        printf ("\nLine [%2d]: \"%s\"\n\n", cnt, lineptr);

        /* parse line into integers */
        parent = 1;
        sptr = NULL;
        eptr = lineptr;
        while (*eptr != '\0') {
            if (*eptr != ' ' && sptr == NULL) {
                sptr = eptr;
                eptr++;
            }
            while (*eptr != ' ' && *eptr != '\0') {
                eptr++;
            }

            if (*eptr == '\0') {
                printf ("  add to tree: %d\n", atoi (sptr));
                break;
            }

            if (*eptr == ' ' && sptr != NULL) {
                *eptr = '\0';
                if (parent) {
                    printf ("  add to tree: %d  (parent)\n", atoi (sptr));
                    parent = 0;
                } else {
                    printf ("  add to tree: %d\n", atoi (sptr));
                }
                *eptr = ' ';
                sptr = NULL;
            }

            eptr++;
        }
        cnt++;
    }

    printf ("\nTotal lines parsed: %d\n\n", cnt);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of the sample data is:

```
Line [ 0]: "   52 12 123 1"

add to tree: 52  (parent)
add to tree: 12
add to tree: 123
add to tree: 1

Line [ 1]: "   4 2 11"

add to tree: 4  (parent)
add to tree: 2
add to tree: 11

Line [ 2]: "   9 88 1 23 42"

add to tree: 9  (parent)
add to tree: 88
add to tree: 1
add to tree: 23
add to tree: 42

Total lines parsed: 3
```

I'm sure there is a faster way to do it, but simply stepping though the lines with pointers eliminates quite a bit of overhead that would be required in calls to string functions. I don't know what type tree you were considering, but this code provides an easy way to add the insert routines where the current printfs are.

Answer (score 0):

I think conditional loops will be useful in this case .
The basic flow would be like this

```
do
{
   Read the first integer using fscanf

   if next character is not End of Line i.e. \n or EOF 
   {        
         read rest of line till end of Line  
         store the numerical into a temp array
         read from array and append them into tree

   }
} while (EOF)
```